# node.js + express API status code 200 but client still pending

Tags: node.js, jquery, express

I've got a very simple and straightforward API written in Node.js and Express that works just fine, but every now and then, the `jQuery.post` call will remain "Pending" (and eventually timeout). On the server side, I've monitored the request and result and it is logging a `200` response code with the appropriate data in ~40ms. No matter how many times I refresh the page (the data in the call is static, not based on inputs), the request completes successfully on the server, but hangs in the client. If I restart the node.js server script, all is well and normal function on the client is restored.

It ran smooth without a restart for the last 3 days, then about one hour after I restarted the script I had to do it again. Been fine now for the last 2 hours.

- Node.js v0.10.10
- Express v3.2.6

Any insight would be helpful. Thanks.

**EDIT** - Adding code
This is the function that is hanging.

```
exports.getDistinct = function(req, res) {
var params = {
    filter:     function() {
                    var filter = getParams(req, 'filter');
                    if ( filter ) {
                        f = {};
                        for (var key in filter)
                            f[key] = { $in: filter[key] }

                        var search = getParams(req, 'search');
                        if ( search ) {
                            for (var key in search) {
                                f[key] = new RegExp(helper.escapeRegExp(search[key]),"gi");
                            }
                        }
                        return f;
                    } else {
                        // send error
                        send(req,res,{'error': 'no filter specified'}, 500);
                    }
                }(),
    field:      function() {
                    var field = getParams(req, 'field');
                    if ( field ) return field;
                    else send(req,res,{'error': 'no field specified'}, 500);
                }(),
};

//console.log(util.inspect(params,false, null));
db.results.distinct(
    params.field,
    params.filter,
    function(err, results) {
        if (err) send(req,res,err,500);
        if (params.field == 'Title') {
            var filtered = [];
            db.testcases.find().sort( { _id: 1 } ,function(err, tcnames) {
                if (err) send(req,res,err,500);

                for (var i=0;i<results.length;++i) {
                    if (results[i].match(/^up/gi)) {
                        tcnames.filter( function(tc) { 
                            if (tc._id == results[i]) filtered.push(tc);
                        });
                    } 
                }
                filtered.sort(helper.compare);
                send(req,res,filtered,200);
            });
        } else {
            send(req,res,results,200);
        }
    }
);
}
```

And here is the code for the `send` function being used:
    function send(req, res, data, status) {
    var isJsonp = req.query.hasOwnProperty('callback');
    if (!status) status = 200;
    if (isJsonp) res.send(req.query['callback']+'('+JSON.stringify(data)+')', status);
    else res.send(data, status);
    }

**EDIT** just noticed this in `httpd.conf` and I have no idea if its relevant:

```
BrowserMatch "Mozilla/2" nokeepalive
BrowserMatch "MSIE 4\.0b2;" nokeepalive downgrade-1.0 force-response-1.0
BrowserMatch "RealPlayer 4\.0" force-response-1.0
BrowserMatch "Java/1\.0" force-response-1.0
BrowserMatch "JDK/1\.0" force-response-1.0

BrowserMatch "Microsoft Data Access Internet Publishing Provider" redirect-carefully
BrowserMatch "MS FrontPage" redirect-carefully
BrowserMatch "^WebDrive" redirect-carefully
BrowserMatch "^WebDAVFS/1.[0123]" redirect-carefully
BrowserMatch "^gnome-vfs/1.0" redirect-carefully
BrowserMatch "^XML Spy" redirect-carefully
BrowserMatch "^Dreamweaver-WebDAV-SCM1" redirect-carefully
```

Comment: It's a bug in line 42 of your server.js code. Oh wait, you didn't post any code snippets!

Comment: I did not see the code as relevant because I was getting proper server activity in addition to a restart with absolutely no changes solved the problem temporarily. But I have obliged.

Comment: Is this just TCP keepalive? Does the browser developer tools show you the response body has arrived in the browser?

Comment: The browser dev tools (Chrome in this case, but the behavior is across all browsers) shows NO response from the server, and the request is in the perpetual state of `(pending)`.

Comment: I just attached an httpd.conf excerpt that I quite honestly have no idea if its relevant or useful.

Answer (score 1):

So usually these symptoms mean your logic within your request handler has a branch that isn't properly terminated by responding to the request or omits a guard clause `return` statement. I think this is an error in your code, and there may be other cases:

```
if (err) send(req,res,err,500);
```

That's a bug. It will send a response but continue executing the remainder of the function, resulting in misbehavior. You want:

```
if (err){ 
  return send(req,res,err,500);
}
```

I think that's your only bug, but it's a good idea to A) try to keep your logic small enough and simple enough to make it easy to visually confirm every branch terminates with an HTTP response and a `return` statement where appropriate and then B) when things necessarily get larger or more branchy, consider using `return` whenever you send a response as a defensive coding technique.